# Why is rsi high sometimes lower than rsi low?

Tags: tradingview-api

I've noticed this on indicators coded by others but now that I'm trying to code my own rsi indicator with both rsi low and high in the same indicator subpanel that they're crossing each other all over the place. Is this a flaw in how trading view calculates rsi?

Theoretically rsi low would plot the lowest rsi went during the candle and rsi high would do the same for the highest. There's no reason they should cross. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

This is currently what I have for code.

```
`//@version=5
indicator(title='RSI high and low', shorttitle='RSI high and low', overlay=false)

rsiLength = input(14, title="RSI Length")

rsiUpperBand = hline(70, 'RSI Upper Band', color=#ffffff)
midline = hline(50, 'RSI Middle Band', color=color.new(#ffffff, 0))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, 'RSI Lower Band', color=#ffffff)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(110, 6, 238, 82), title="RSI Background Fill")

// Calculate RSI for high and low
rsiHigh = ta.highest(ta.rsi(high, rsiLength), 1)
rsiLow = ta.lowest(ta.rsi(low, rsiLength), 1)

plot(rsiHigh, color=color.rgb(243, 245, 246), title='RSI High')
plot(rsiLow, color=color.rgb(69, 94, 230), title='RSI Low')`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code only calculate the RSI based on the high and low prices respectively, and then finds the highest and lowest value of those RSIs over the last 1 period. This cause the RSI high and RSI low to cross each other, as they are not directly related to each other.
To calculate the highest RSI value and the lowest RSI value during a candle, you should first calculate the RSI based on the closing prices, and then find the highest and lowest RSI within a period.

I have updated your code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='RSI high and low', shorttitle='RSI high and low', overlay=false)

rsiLength = input(14, title="RSI Length")
rsiPeriod = input(14, title="RSI Period for High and Low")

rsiUpperBand = hline(70, 'RSI Upper Band', color=#ffffff)
midline = hline(50, 'RSI Middle Band', color=color.new(#ffffff, 0))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, 'RSI Lower Band', color=#ffffff)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(110, 6, 238, 82), title="RSI Background Fill")

// Calculate RSI
rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsiLength)

// Find highest and lowest RSI within a period
rsiHigh = ta.highest(rsi, rsiPeriod)
rsiLow = ta.lowest(rsi, rsiPeriod)

plot(rsiHigh, color=color.rgb(243, 245, 246), title='RSI High')
plot(rsiLow, color=color.rgb(69, 94, 230), title='RSI Low')
```

rsiPeriod is the length of the period over which you want to find the highest and lowest RSI.

Comment: The "period" that I want the highest and lowest rsi from is within each candle. Ive attached a picture of the results of your code and mine.  Yours is on the bottom.  If I edit your "rsi period" to one, the period I want the candle to calculate the high and low for, they're equal because they're just reporting the close of each candle.  I appreciate your help but this isn't what I'm looking for.  https://postimg.cc/TL9f2SWr

Comment: I see your point, but the issue here is related to how RSI and candlestick data are calculated.
In a single candlestick, you have four pieces of information: the open, close, high, and low. 
However, the RSI isn't calculated based on these individual pieces of data. Basically it is from a series of closing prices over a certain period like RSI 14d or 7d. The RSI itself doesn't have a concept of the 'highest' or 'lowest' point within a single candle.

Comment: When you are calculating rsiHigh and rsiLow in your code, actually  itrepresents the highest and lowest RSI values over the previous candle which is not within the same candle. 
As rsiHigh and rsiLow are calculated over different data sets, so why they can cross each other. (Already off-topic from stackoverflow)